# add template to page attributes wp

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

i'm use this code:

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'calendar_load' ); 
function calendar_load( $template ) {
    if ( is_page( 'calendar' ) ) {
        $template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/calendar-page.php';
        return $template;  
    }
}
```

He is workin if my page name "calendar"
But i want see my templete in page attributes in wp theme. How i can do it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF1wJ.jpg)